# Issue using LIKE in a SQL query with special characters in it

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT id, absolute_tag, tag FROM c7_storage_tags
WHERE users_id = 1 
      AND LOWER(absolute_tag) LIKE LOWER('@#Pictures#zee\'s fav%')
```

This is not giving me the correct result, even thou i do have a row in my database with the correct string.

The better solution for me would be to figure out a way so that "@#Pictures#zee\'s fav" string of mine, could be treated as just a string. And I can perform like on it.

How can I fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Zeeshan

Comment: Could you give a bit more data. for example more values from absolute_tag columns

Comment: The absolute_tag column, has the folder paths, eg there is a folder in the Documents folder name TestFolder, so the data in absolute path would be @#Documents#TestFolder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you string has a backslash in it, you should escape it twice :

```
// value absolute_tag == "@#Pictures#zee\'s fav"
select * from test where  `absolute_tag` like '@#Pictures#zee\\\\\'%'
```

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Your query should look like

```
SELECT id, absolute_tag, tag FROM c7_storage_tags
WHERE users_id = 1 
AND LOWER(absolute_tag) LIKE LOWER('@#Pictures#zee\\\\\'s fav%')
```

Your original query was looking for a record with absoulte_tags begins with "@#Pictures#zee's fav"

Comment: Thanks alot. can you also tell me how can I use $shared_tag_path = str_replace('\','\\\\\',$string_name_var); in php to escape the back-slash. I guess php does not allows '\'

Comment: I cannot tell you right of the bat since I cannot test right now, I believe it should be `str_replace('\\','\\\\\\\\', $string_name_var);`